# Foreach iteration in knockout js on two collections at once in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have the following table.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: TuDispTexts, foreach: ApplicationTexts">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: DictionaryTextId"></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: TuDispTexts.Culture" type="text"/></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: TuDispTexts.DictionaryValue" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: ApplicationTexts.DictionaryValue" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Is that possible to iterate on two collections at once and accessing two them by name like I presented? The proposed solution is not working.

Function to define model.

```
function tuDispModel() {
        this.AetrState = ko.observable();
        this.TuDispTexts = ko.observable;
        this.ApplicationTexts = ko.observable();

        this.texts = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            return tuDispInfo.TuDispTexts.map(function (tu, index) {
                return { tu: tu, app: tuDispInfo.ApplicationTexts[index] };
            });
        })
```

;
    }

Order of call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        tuDispInfo = new tuDispModel();
        getTuDispData(corewebApiUrl, tuDispId);
        ko.applyBindings(tuDispInfo);
    });
```

Comment: @NisargShah in given soltion they get to array by index. How can I get to the propery in my case?

Comment: You could use `with: $root.arr1()[$index()]` to bind to the correct array item, and then access properties normally, like `text: Culture`.

Comment: @NisargShah could you write an example how to get?

Comment: I have got that '<td><input data-bind="value: $root.TuDispTexts()
@NisargShah [$index()].DictionaryValue" type="text" /></td>
                                <td><input data-bind="value: $root.ApplicationTexts()[$index()].DictionaryValue" type="text" /></td>'

Comment: @NisargShah I receive in browser: Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return $root.ApplicationTexts()[$index()].DictionaryValue }"
Message: Cannot read property 'DictionaryValue' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Assuming that `TuDispTexts` and `ApplicationTexts` are parallel collections (e.g., `TuDispTexts[0]` relates to `ApplicationTexts[0]`, `TuDispTexts[1]` relates to `ApplicationTexts[1]`, etc.), you'll want to create a computed collection that references both of them, then iterate over that.

E.g. (this is a *sketch*, not perfect code you can just plunk into your project):

```
vm.texts = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return vm.TuDispTexts.map(function(tu, index) {
        return {tu: tu, app: vm.ApplicationTexts[index]};
    });
});
```

... then

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: texts">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: /*Unclear where this comes from: DictionaryTextId*/"></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: texts.tu.Culture" type="text"/></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: texts.tu.DictionaryValue" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: texts.app.DictionaryValue" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: This vm.texts is JS function? Should it be in tag script?

Comment: @maciejka: That block is JavaScript. You'd include it in your view model, making any necessary changes.

Comment: I updated the problem. It is not displaying and is problem with mapping. tuDispInfo.TuDispTexts.map is not a function

Comment: @maciejka: *"this is a sketch, not perfect code you can just plunk into your project"* *"making any necessary changes"*